# mysql change to laravel on count and rightjoin

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder, laravel-9

I have a question on mysql changing to Laravel

Here is my code on mysql

```
SELECT raceseriesmap.rs_id,raceseriesmap.m_id,raceseriesmap.rsm_mo , raceseriesmap.rsm_extra, mapdata.m_name, mapdata.m_photoname,  
(SELECT count(carinraceseries.crs_id)  from carinraceseries WHERE carinraceseries.rs_id = raceseriesmap.rs_id)  as c_count from raceseriesmap 
right join mapdata on mapdata.m_id = raceseriesmap.m_id
where raceseriesmap.m_id =4
```

here is my Laravel code

```
        DB::table('raceseriesmap')
        ->select('raceseriesmap.rs_id', 'raceseriesmap.m_id', 'raceseriesmap.rsm_mo', 'raceseriesmap.rsm_extra', 'mapdata.m_name', 'mapdata.m_photoname', 'carinraceseries.crs_id as c_count')
        ->rightJoin('mapdata','mapdata.m_id','=','raceseriesmap.m_id')
        ->where('raceseriesmap.m_id','=',4)
        ->get();
```

but the result showing like this

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'carinraceseries.crs_id' in 'field list'
select
  `raceseriesmap`.`rs_id`,
  `raceseriesmap`.`m_id`,
  `raceseriesmap`.`rsm_mo`,
  `raceseriesmap`.`rsm_extra`,
  `mapdata`.`m_name`,
  `mapdata`.`m_photoname`,
  `carinraceseries`.`crs_id` as `c_count`
from
  `raceseriesmap`
  right join `mapdata` on `mapdata`.`m_id` = `raceseriesmap`.`m_id`
where
  `raceseriesmap`.`m_id` = 4
```

Comment: Your rightJoin looks fine, doesn't it?

Comment: You need to explain what your question is. You have explained the context, but I wonder what you are wondering about.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a sub query in your SELECT statement aka sub select using [`DB::raw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions):

```
DB::table('raceseriesmap')
    ->select(
        'raceseriesmap.rs_id',
        'raceseriesmap.m_id',
        'raceseriesmap.rsm_mo',
        'raceseriesmap.rsm_extra',
        'mapdata.m_name',
        'mapdata.m_photoname',
        DB::raw("(SELECT count(carinraceseries.crs_id)  from carinraceseries WHERE carinraceseries.rs_id = raceseriesmap.rs_id)  as c_count")
    )
    ->rightJoin('mapdata','mapdata.m_id','=','raceseriesmap.m_id')
    ->where('raceseriesmap.m_id','=',4)
    ->get();
```